# Keyboard hides the input field in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".StreamActivity"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/streamLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </SurfaceView>

</FrameLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

FrameLayout for a video player. WebView is a chat.
When I begin to type text into the chat, the keyboard hides input field.

I tried experimenting with android: windowSoftInputMode, but it does not work for me. The problem with chat, it is written on Angular and resizing WebView does not change the size of the chat, it must be done manually like webView.loadUrl("javascript: $('section.content-window:first').css('height', '" + finalSize + "px');");

I have a listener that is triggered when the keyboard is shown and hidden.
I would like to manually change the size of the chat when the keyboard is showed, but it does not work well because when I change the size of chat it loses focus and the keyboard hidden.

I also thought to put the content of the Activity in ScrollView. If override OnTouchListener this will lock scroll by user, but I will still be able to scroll from code. So, I wanted if the keyboard is shown then scroll content of the Activity so it would be visible the entire chat. I think this will work, but not good because it will lock the scrolling in WebView.

Advise how to fix this problem with the keyboard and chat?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<ScrollView ...
        <LinearLayout ...
            ...
            <com.package.TouchyWebView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/webView"/>
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and do like this

```
package com.mypackage.common.custom.android.widgets

public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {

    public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }          
}
```

and

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
            }
        });
```

and to scroll I use code like this

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
boolean isOpen = false;
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            if (!isOpen) {
                scrollView.scrollBy(0, heightDiff);
                isOpen = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (isOpen) {
                scrollView.scrollBy(0, -heightDiff);
                isOpen = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, can you tell us where did you get heightDiff? Thanks